# Generate DISTINCT Lists with ID T-SQL

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, distinct-values

For use in SSRS multi-select dropdowns, I need to generate multiple DISTINCT lists of values.

This is easily done. `Select DISTINCT Department from DimEmployee`

In order to set an SSRS default value, you must have an ID field also in your data set.. this is not achieved by the above query

I need to assign an arbitrary uniqueID to each of these records from my distinct list

Any advice appreciated.

Final output would be:

```
Select * From dsDeptList
```

Results...

```
ID   |   DeptName

1    |   DeptName1
2    |   DeptName2
etc.....
```

Comment: You could use `ROW_NUMBER` SQL function after `DISTINCT`. Also, you should use `sql-server` tag if this is your DBMS.

Comment: That is just odd the you could have column named EmployeeID with duplicate values. What is the table definition?

Comment: Employee ID was an example and I do not have duplicate values.  I need a list of (real example, employee Departments).  We do not have a Department Table, it is only tied to the employee.  So I can get a distinct list of depts, but I then need to assign them arbitraty ID's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just include the EmployeeID column twice (with column aliases). Use it as the ID and the value. The DISTINCT guarantees it's unique in the resultset.

Comment: THIS WORKS.. but..I have the two columns now, and SSRS won't populate it with a default.  I tried doing a left() on my id field but no luck.  It must be something with SSRS.  But this did answer my question.  New question for the SSRS issue..

Comment: Can you elaborate on "Won't populated it with a default"?

Comment: Yes, when you set a default value to a multiselect list, and then preview the report there would be no need to click into the drop down unless to change from the default value.

Comment: Although I have a default value set, the parameter is not automatically selecting it upon RUN

Comment: Are you certain the default value you're setting exactly matches one of the values returned by your query including case?

Comment: Yes I am Pulling, `distinct PayrollType, PayrollType as TypeID`

I think the issue is that it is looking for a different value, not just a different column?

Comment: Shouldn't matter. What are you putting in for default value?

Comment: I'm using the TypeID field for value field.  And PayrollType as the Label Field.

Comment: Right. That's good. Now in the default values for the parameter, you put one the values from that dataset. Exact spelling including case. And if you want the default to be "select all" then you can use that same dataset as the source of default values.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code:

```
CREATE TABLE #Test(EmpName VARCHAR(10));

INSERT #Test VALUES('A'),('A'),('B'),('C'),('C');

SELECT DISTINCT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY EmpName) ID,EmpName
FROM #Test;

DROP TABLE #Test;
```

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

I think **GROUP BY** should solve your problem

```
SELECT EmployeeID,EmpName FROM YourTable
GROUP BY EmployeeID,EmpName
```

You'll definitely avoid dublications

Comment: It would not eliminate duplicate EmpName

Comment: Exactly and that is my issue.  I need to assign NEW id's to my distinct list, after the fact